# Игра угадывания чисел Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript

Выскакивает ошибка

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token.

Не пойму в чем ошибка - вроде все правильно прописываю.
Кто в чем видит мою ошибку- что нужно поправить?

```js
class Game {
  constructor(config) {
    this.min = min;
    this.max = max;
    this.guesses = document.querySelector(config.guesses);
    this.lustResult = document.querySelector(config.lustResult);
    this.lowOrHi = document.querySelector(config.lowOrHi);
    this.guessField = document.querySelector(config.guessField);
    this.guesSubmit = document.querySelector(config.guesSubmit);
    this.guessCount = 1;
    this.resetButton;
    this.randomIntenger();
    this.checkGuess();


  }


  randomIntenger() {
    var rand = this.min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (this.max - this.min + 1)
    this.randomNumber = Math.round(rand);
    return this.randomNumber;
  }

  checkGuess() {
    if (this.guessField.value === "") {
      alert("Заполните пустое поле!");
      return
    }
    var userGeuss = Number(this.guessField.value); //проверяем число или буква
    if (this.guessCount === 1) {
      this.guesses.textContent = "Предыдущие числа: ";
    }
    this.guesses.textContent += userGeuss + " ";

    if (userGeuss === this.randomNumber) {
      this.lustResult.textContent = alert("Поздравляю вы угадали число");
      this.lustResult.style.background = 'green';
      this.lowOrHi.textContent = '';
      this.setGameOver();
    } else if (this.guessCount === 3) {
      this.lustResult.textContent = 'Ваши попытки закончились. Игра окончена';
      this.lustResult.style.background = 'blue';
      this.setGameOver();
    } else {
      this.lustResult.textContent = "Не верно";
      this.lustResult.style.background = 'red';
      if (userGeuss < this.randomNumber) {
        this.lowOrHi.textContent = "Теплее";
        this.lowOrHi.style.background = 'yellow';
      } else if (userGeuss > rthis.andomNumber) {
        this.lowOrHi.textContent = "Холодно";
        this.lowOrHi.style.background = 'blue';
      }
    }
    this.guessCount++;
    this.guessField.value = '';
    this.guessField.focus();
  }

  this.guesSubmit.addEventListener('click', this.checkGuessbind);

  setGameOver() {
    this.guessField.disabled = true;
    this.guesSubmit.disabled = true;
    this.resetButton = document.createElement('button');
    this.resetButton.textContent = 'Новая игра';
    document.body.appendChild(this.resetButton);
    this.resetButton.addEventListener('click', resetGame);
  }

  resetGame() {
    this.guessCount = 1;

    var resetParam = document.querySelectorAll('.resultParam p');
    for (var i = 0; i < resetParam.length; i++) {
      console.log(resetParam[i].textContent);
      resetParam[i].textContent = '';
    }

    this.resetButton.parentNode.removeChild(this.resetButton);

    this.guessField.disabled = false;
    this.guesSubmit.disabled = false;

    this.guessField.value = '';
    this.guessField.focus();

    this.lustResult.style.background = 'white';

    this.randomNumber = randomItenger(1, 5);
  }

}




var game = new Game({
  min: 1,
  max: 5,
  guesses: '.guesses',
  lustResult: '.lustResult',
  lowOrHi: '.lowOrHi',
  guessField: '.guessField',
  guesSubmit: '.guesSubmit'
});

console.log();
```

```css
.lustResult {
  width: 30%;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.lowOrHi {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<!-- Используя ооп, создать игру, которая загадывает целое РАНДОМНОЕ число от min до max ! У пользователя есть три попытки его угадать. Количество оставшихся попыток красиво выводятся в дом, угадывает он через инпут. Также нужно давать подсказки человеку (например "тепло" или "холодно") по отношению к угадываемому числу, подсказки сначало не активны. Активируй их, например, с помощью чекбокса -->
<!-- Так же было бы хорошо, придумать где можно сделать наследование -->
<div class="vrapper">
  <h1>Угадайте число</h1>
  <p>мы загодали ранодомное число от .. до .. У вас есть 3 попытки угадать</p>
  <div class="form">
    <label for="guessField">Введите число: </label>
    <input type="text" id="guessField" class="guessField">
    <input type="submit" value="Угадать" class="guesSubmit">
  </div>
  <div class="resultParam">
    <p class="guesses"></p>
    <p class="lustResult"></p>
    <p class="lowOrHi"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

строка

```
this.guesSubmit.addEventListener('click', this.checkGuessbind);
```

находится вне тела любого из методов. Поэтому `this` в данном случается рассматривается как имя метода за которым должно следовать определение, однако в данном случае следует символ точки. Поэтому и происходит указанная ошибка.

Для решения нужно внести данный код в один из уже описанных методов. Вероятнее всего он должен быть внутри `checkGuess`:

```js
class Game {
  constructor(config) {
    this.min = min;
    this.max = max;
    this.guesses = document.querySelector(config.guesses);
    this.lustResult = document.querySelector(config.lustResult);
    this.lowOrHi = document.querySelector(config.lowOrHi);
    this.guessField = document.querySelector(config.guessField);
    this.guesSubmit = document.querySelector(config.guesSubmit);
    this.guessCount = 1;
    this.resetButton;
    this.randomIntenger();
    this.checkGuess();


  }


  randomIntenger() {
    var rand = this.min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (this.max - this.min + 1)
    this.randomNumber = Math.round(rand);
    return this.randomNumber;
  }

  checkGuess() {
    if (this.guessField.value === "") {
      alert("Заполните пустое поле!");
      return
    }
    var userGeuss = Number(this.guessField.value); //проверяем число или буква
    if (this.guessCount === 1) {
      this.guesses.textContent = "Предыдущие числа: ";
    }
    this.guesses.textContent += userGeuss + " ";

    if (userGeuss === this.randomNumber) {
      this.lustResult.textContent = alert("Поздравляю вы угадали число");
      this.lustResult.style.background = 'green';
      this.lowOrHi.textContent = '';
      this.setGameOver();
    } else if (this.guessCount === 3) {
      this.lustResult.textContent = 'Ваши попытки закончились. Игра окончена';
      this.lustResult.style.background = 'blue';
      this.setGameOver();
    } else {
      this.lustResult.textContent = "Не верно";
      this.lustResult.style.background = 'red';
      if (userGeuss < this.randomNumber) {
        this.lowOrHi.textContent = "Теплее";
        this.lowOrHi.style.background = 'yellow';
      } else if (userGeuss > rthis.andomNumber) {
        this.lowOrHi.textContent = "Холодно";
        this.lowOrHi.style.background = 'blue';
      }
    }
    this.guessCount++;
    this.guessField.value = '';
    this.guessField.focus();
    this.guesSubmit.addEventListener('click', this.checkGuessbind);
  }



  setGameOver() {
    this.guessField.disabled = true;
    this.guesSubmit.disabled = true;
    this.resetButton = document.createElement('button');
    this.resetButton.textContent = 'Новая игра';
    document.body.appendChild(this.resetButton);
    this.resetButton.addEventListener('click', resetGame);
  }

  resetGame() {
    this.guessCount = 1;

    var resetParam = document.querySelectorAll('.resultParam p');
    for (var i = 0; i < resetParam.length; i++) {
      console.log(resetParam[i].textContent);
      resetParam[i].textContent = '';
    }

    this.resetButton.parentNode.removeChild(this.resetButton);

    this.guessField.disabled = false;
    this.guesSubmit.disabled = false;

    this.guessField.value = '';
    this.guessField.focus();

    this.lustResult.style.background = 'white';

    this.randomNumber = randomItenger(1, 5);
  }

}




var game = new Game({
  min: 1,
  max: 5,
  guesses: '.guesses',
  lustResult: '.lustResult',
  lowOrHi: '.lowOrHi',
  guessField: '.guessField',
  guesSubmit: '.guesSubmit'
});

console.log();
```

```css
.lustResult {
  width: 30%;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.lowOrHi {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<!-- Используя ооп, создать игру, которая загадывает целое РАНДОМНОЕ число от min до max ! У пользователя есть три попытки его угадать. Количество оставшихся попыток красиво выводятся в дом, угадывает он через инпут. Также нужно давать подсказки человеку (например "тепло" или "холодно") по отношению к угадываемому числу, подсказки сначало не активны. Активируй их, например, с помощью чекбокса -->
<!-- Так же было бы хорошо, придумать где можно сделать наследование -->
<div class="vrapper">
  <h1>Угадайте число</h1>
  <p>мы загодали ранодомное число от .. до .. У вас есть 3 попытки угадать</p>
  <div class="form">
    <label for="guessField">Введите число: </label>
    <input type="text" id="guessField" class="guessField">
    <input type="submit" value="Угадать" class="guesSubmit">
  </div>
  <div class="resultParam">
    <p class="guesses"></p>
    <p class="lustResult"></p>
    <p class="lowOrHi"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93711/discussion-on-answer-by-grundy----uncaught-syntaxerror-unexp).

Comment: задача решена проблема была в том, что я в конструкторе вызывал метод checkGuess
убрал и все заработало ))

Comment: @олегстоянов, ок.